# Django url problem

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I'm getting this error

```
error at /
unknown specifier: ?P&
```

and I suppose it's coming from this line

```
(r'^(?P&lt;template&gt;\w+)/$', static_page),
```

I copied this from a tutorial, how do I fix this error ?

Comment: Need more information - what URL are you trying to access? And what is the rest of urls.py? And if you want people to help you, you need to accept answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use

```
r'^(?P<template>\w+)/$'
```

for your regex. You seem to have copied the regex with HTML entities still encoded; the regex engine expects verbatim `<`  and `>`.